# In web applications, which is more realible, 1 join query for 4 tables or 4 individual database calls?

Tags: mysql, database, join

In PHP, what is more efficient?

- 1 join query to 4 tables OR
- 4 individual database calls?

Limit will be maximum 10 in every case.

The tables are:

```
approvals
id  |  content  |  user_id  |  time_stamp

users
id  |  name  |  email

labels
id  |  name

label_relations
id  |  label_id  |  approval_id
```

Comment: Could you please provide `CREATE TABLE` for your tables and what exact result you want to achieve? What do you mean by "reliable"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One complex (but efficiently composed) call will beat 4 simple calls.

The reason is that making a database call has a large overhead, typically more than the query itself. There is:

- Opening a transaction
- Parsing the query
- Checking authorization
- Calculating the plan
- Establishing the transport of results
- Closing the transaction

All of which have nothing to do with getting data. You avoid doing all this (and more) 3 times by making one call.

Just make sure your query is well written - eg consider unions

Comment: Agreed. One query that is horribly written could always become less efficient than 4 individual calls; but one solid query should be faster than 4, since you're asking the SQL server to do what it is optimized to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you code your queries correctly, both will be equally reliable.

Maybe *reliable* isn't [the word you're looking for](http://thesaurus.com/browse/reliable).